# Tengo 2 JSON como entrada y debo generar 1 resultado específico con esas entradas

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject

Soy principiante en Javascript, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, mi problema es que tengo dos entradas en formato JSON y debo obtener un resultado específico (el que menciono más adelante) y no sé como resolverlo.

- Tengo estos dos JSON iniciales como entradas:

```javascript
// JSON 
       let values =  {
            1: {
                carrier: "CCH",
                service: "DEX",
            },
            17: {
                carrier: "CHP",
                service: "express",
            }
       }
      // JSON
       let json = { 
                    data: {
                        LIMA: {
                            limit: 1,
                            over_carrier_service_id: 17,
                            under_carrier_service_id: 17
                        },
                        QUITO: {
                            limit: 1,
                            over_carrier_service_id: 1,
                            under_carrier_service_id: 1
                        },
                        CARACAS: {
                            limit: 1,
                            over_carrier_service_id: 1,
                            under_carrier_service_id: 1
                        },
                        SANTIAGO: {
                            limit: 1,
                            over_carrier_service_id: 17,
                            under_carrier_service_id: 17
                        }
                    }
                }
```

- Y debo generar un script que con estas entradas genere el siguiente resultado:

```javascript
let result = {
            LIMA: {
                limit: 1,
                over: {
                    carrier: "CHP",
                    service: "express",
                },
                under: {
                    carrier: "CHP",
                    service: "express",
                }
            },
            QUITO: {
                limit: 1,
                over: {
                    carrier: "CCH",
                    service: "DEX",
                },
                under: {
                     carrier: "CCH",
                    service: "DEX",
                }
            },
            CARACAS: {
                limit: 1,
                over: {
                    carrier: "CCH",
                    service: "DEX",
                },
                under: {
                     carrier: "CCH",
                    service: "DEX",
                }
            },
            SANTIAGO: {
                limit: 1,
                over: {
                    carrier: "CHP",
                    service: "express",
                },
                under: {
                    carrier: "CHP",
                    service: "express",
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: Hola DevGirl Bienvenid@ a stack :D ¿has intentado hacer algo para solucionar tu problema? Recuerda que stack es una comunidad que incentiva la investigación y el tomar la acción. Te recomiendo que leas ¿[Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? y que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), un saludo y no te desanimes.

Comment: Puedes intentar con rxjs, si tienes conocimiento de eso con algunos map puedes modificar el resultado como gustes

Answer (score -1):

Una posible solución sería la siguiente:

1. Acceder al `Object` `data` del `Object` padre `json` y obtener un array con sus claves, en este caso las ciuidades: `Object.keys(json.data)`
2. Bucle `forEach` sobre el array de ciudades. También vale el bucle tradicional `for (let i = 0; i<cities.length; i++)`.
3. Crear `Object` `result` vacío.
4. Procesamiento necesario en cada iteración:

   - Guardar la variable `limit` (con el límite), `over`, y `under` (con los índices proporcionados por el json de la ciudad).
   - Añadir en el `Object` `result` un nuevo atributo que tenga como clave el nombre de la ciudad y valor un nuevo `Object` con atributos `limit`(el límite), `over` y `under` (respectivos objetos creados a partir del json result con los índices guardados en el paso anterior)

No hay un método nativa `map` para los `Object`. Los `map` sirven para transformar un array de entrada en otro array de salida tal y como se indica en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).

```js
let values = {
    1: {
        carrier: "CCH",
        service: "DEX",
    },
    17: {
        carrier: "CHP",
        service: "express",
    }
}

// JSON
let json = {
    data: {
        LIMA: {
            limit: 1,
            over_carrier_service_id: 17,
            under_carrier_service_id: 17
        },
        QUITO: {
            limit: 1,
            over_carrier_service_id: 1,
            under_carrier_service_id: 1
        },
        CARACAS: {
            limit: 1,
            over_carrier_service_id: 1,
            under_carrier_service_id: 1
        },
        SANTIAGO: {
            limit: 1,
            over_carrier_service_id: 17,
            under_carrier_service_id: 17
        }
    }
}

//solution
let result = {}
Object.keys(json.data).forEach(city => {
    const limit = json.data[city].limit
    const over =  json.data[city].over_carrier_service_id
    const under = json.data[city].under_carrier_service_id
    result[city] = {
        limit: limit,
        over: {
            carrier: values[over].carrier,
            service: values[over].service
        },
        under: {
            carrier: values[under].carrier,
            service: values[under].service
        }
    }
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por esa posible respuesta @javicond3 !! Si es posible, me lo podrías explicar para entender lo que hiciste por favor, solo se me ocurría que se podía resolver con .map

Comment: Por favor, podrías comentar lo que haces para que quede más claro?

Comment: He editado la respuesta añadiendo una breve explicación. @cooper